# Remove link from page title

Tags: customization, title

How can I remove the link from the page title in my WordPress theme?

Here's the link to my test [site](http://leon-aver.com/) and below is the code responsible for that:

```
<h1 class='post-title <?php echo $titleClass; ?>'>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php 
        _e('Permanent Link:','avia_framework')?> <?php 
        the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</h1>
```

When I removed `<a href=""> </a>`, it removed the complete title and nothing is visible.

*Edit:* I want the title to remain on the page, but not linked to the post.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps when you removed your a tag you also remove the nested `the_title();` function?

`the_title();` is the Wordpress function which spits out the plain text post/page title so having that in your h1 like below should get you the results you're expecting. Of course there may also be some CSS which is affected due to the removal of your `<a>` tag

```
<h1 class='post-title <?php echo $titleClass; ?>'>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove a `<a>` teg only use `<?php the_title(); ?>` in h1  teg 
another 
below code add in function.php

```
add_action('wp_head' , 'remove_post_list_title_links');
function remove_post_list_title_links() {
    ?>
    <script id="remove-links-in-title" type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('.entry-title').each(function() {
                var $title_link = $('a[rel="bookmark"]' , $(this)),
                    $title_text = $title_link.text();
                $title_link.remove();
                $(this).prepend($title_text);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```